# How do I remove Cell Padding in jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

How do I remove the padding when using .cell in jsPDF?

I've looked everywhere and the documentation is vague

```
this.pdf = new jsPDF();
this.pdf.cell(0, 0, 10, 10, "cell cell cell cell cell cell cell");
this.pdf.cell(10, 0, 10, 10, cell cell cell cell cell cell cell);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

If you first call the table function with padding 0, then all cell calls load with padding 0:

```
this.pdf = new jsPDF();
this.pdf.table(0,0,[],[],{padding: 0,})
this.pdf.cell(0, 0, 10, 10, "cell cell cell cell cell cell cell");
this.pdf.cell(10, 0, 10, 10, cell cell cell cell cell cell cell);
```

This work for me.